# Android - How to call method in fragment from activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

How can i call method in fragment from activity?
I searched some code but most of people said use like this,

```
ExampleFragment fragment = (ExampleFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.example_fragment); 
fragment.specific_function_name();
```

but i don't have fragment in my xml

I need another way to call fragment method.

This is method in fragment

```
public void video()
{
    new getVideo().execute();
}
```

And this is my activity

```
public class ActivityTwitch extends AppCompatActivity
{
    Toolbar toolbar;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_twitch);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("개구멍");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                finish();
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new TwitchChannel(), "채널");
        adapter.addFragment(new TwitchStream(), "스트리밍");
        adapter.addFragment(new TwitchFeed(), "게시물");
        adapter.addFragment(new TwitchVideo(), "동영상");

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    public class Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
    {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();

        public Adapter(FragmentManager fm)
        {
            super(fm);
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title)
        {
            mFragments.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitles.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            return mFragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return mFragments.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
        {
            return mFragmentTitles.get(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you added fragment via code and used a tag string when you added your fragment, use *findFragmentByTag()* instead:

```
YourFragmentClass fragment = (YourFragmentClass)fm.findFragmentByTag("yourTag");
```

Comment: I added fragment like this
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new TwitchChannel(), "channel");
        adapter.addFragment(new TwitchStream(), "stream");
        adapter.addFragment(new TwitchFeed(), "feed");
        adapter.addFragment(new TwitchVideo(), "video");
So i can't use findFragmentByTag()